# Calling a post method with a single string parameter using @RequestParam() annotation in spring-web

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am calling this post method to sent a single parameter as a test. I call it from the URL as the following, but get an error why? please give an example of calling Post method using one sing parameter if possible. I don't want to use @RequestBody and @PathVariable annotations.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/cmd")
public String command(@RequestParam() String command) {
    return command;
}
```

Call:

`http://localhost:8080/api/cmd?command=on`

Error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
  This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
  
  There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
```

Updated:

[image]

Comment: Check the @ComponentScan packages.

Comment: Are you using a GET request or a POST request?

Comment: @Erik As in the question, I use Post method.

Comment: Updated,  I can call this Http post method from PostMan but getting error when calling from browser.

Comment: Based on the error message (405 Method not allowed) and the fact that it seems to work from PostMan, I suspect that the problem lies on the client side and that it somehow uses GET instead of POST. But without seeing your client code, that is just a guess. You could try to use the browser developer tool to see the details of the request coming in.